# Contact Form 7 not working with secondary Gmail: what could be the problem?

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail, contact-form-7

Contact form 7 works fine on my primary gmail domain address. But once I add my secondary gmail it does not send to it. My secondary gmail is my domain in which the contact form is attached to. I've tried switching the MX settings around with no success.

so it goes:

domain: 1234.com

Primary gmail: 123@123.com
Secondary gmail: 123@1234.com

Both linked under the same gmail workspace.

It has something to do with the email being a secondary email address. The secondary address works perfectly outside the contact form.

I tried switching the MX configuration around hoping that it was being rejected but that did not work. I've verfied my MX records and they are all proper. Email works great outside of receiving contact form submissions.